# Does Sky go/Silverlight still work on Ubuntu

Tags: wine, pipelight, moonlight

Been playing around trying to get Sky Go/Silverlight to work on a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 install but having no success.

Ive installed Wine, Pipelight, created the plugins, tried running Silverlight 5 and 5.1 and also using "User Agent Overrider" and the Windows/IE11 setting but when i try to view the Sky Go player i'm told i need to install Silverlight and when i check about:plugins the pipelight plugin doesnt show up

Can anyone offer any advice on the solution please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ive tried all the fixes out there and i'm certain silverlight cant work on ubuntu 16.04. no more development from pipelight is the problem